# Getting six bits from a register

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to do some base 64 encoding. I have an array that holds a message of characters (0 - 255 so only 8 bit characters). I need to somehow pull off just six bits for the 6 bit encoding aspect of 64 bit encoding. I then need to access the two bits I didn't use on the first character and the next four of the next character.

I'm not sure how I go about doing this. I can pull one character into al but am unsure how to just access the most significant 6 bits and then take the least significant 2 bits and concatenate that to the next 4 most significant of the next character.

x86
Intel Syntax
32 bit assembly

Comment: Masking and shifting would be good places to begin.

Comment: forget about assembly and x86 to start, either use C or Python or your favorite high level language or just pencil and paper, sort out the masking and shifting algorithm, then it is a simple matter of implementing that in whatever language (x86 assembly, etc).

Comment: Why don't you use some already done routine, what is the point of your effort? If you want to learn this, then the answer should be probably simple, if you want performance, you can search internet for already done solution (although the one I have seen at first google link doesn't look *that* fast, looks like from 80486 ages).

Answer (score 1):

> I can pull one character into al but am unsure how to just access the most significant 6 bits

Just shift `AL` 2 bit positions to the right:

```
mov  al, [esi]
shr  al, 2
```

---

> and then take the least significant 2 bits and concatenate that to the next 4 most significant of the next character.

First make sure to reload the first character in the `AL` register.
Then bring the second character in the `AH` register.
Now rotate the combined register `AX` 2 bit positions to the right.
Finally shift these 6 top bits down to AL to obtain a 6-bit result:

```
mov  ax, [esi]        ;Reloads 1st char in AL, puts 2nd char in AH
ror  ax, 2            ;Puts the desired 6 bits in the top of AX
shr  ax, 10           ;Move it to AL
```

---

If the intent is to continu in this manner, then this is a good place to increment the string pointer:

```
inc  esi
```

For the third character you'll need code similar (but not the same!) to that of the second character.

```
mov  ax, [esi]        ;Reloads 2nd char in AL, puts 3rd char in AH
rol  ax, 2            ;Puts the desired 6 bits in the bottom of AX
and  al, 63           ;Keep 6 bits
```

But for the fourth character it's again easy. Just read it and mask off the unwanted 2 topbits:

```
inc  esi
mov  al, [esi]
and  al, 63
```

---

One final increment on `ESI` and you're set for another 4 characters comming from only 3 bytes:

```
inc  esi
```